# What algorithm used in c++ stl map.find()?

Tags: c++, stl

I knew map is implemented Red-Black Tree.

So I think `map.find()` is implemented Binary Search Algorithm

Is it sure? 
i used map like this:

```
std::map<int,MyObject>
```

Comment: Since `std::map::find` as a logarithmic time complexity this strongly suggests binary search. If you want to know how it's actually implemented, you should have a look at the `map` header in your include directory.

Comment: Remark: gcc 4.6.3 uses red black trees and simply traverse the tree in a binary fashion. Have a look at `<include>/bits/stl_tree.h` and search for `find`, `_M_lower_bound`. Keep in mind that `_S_left`, `_S_right` return the left/right successors and not the next element in an iteration. Also don't get insane if you look at the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library standard doesn't specify any particular implementation, just requirements for behaviour and performance characteristics. In particular, `find()` must take logarithmic time, which in practice requires something like a binary search.

A red-black tree, or other balanced search tree, is a common implementation.

Comment: Uhm. Binary search works by interval halving. `std::map::find` almost certainly does *not* do that, unless you consider tree traversal to be interval halving (since you ignore potential subtrees). Not sure if that’s a common terminology. It seems to stretch the definition.

Comment: @KonradRudolph From just a slightly different point of view, a balanced binary tree is nothing but one possible implementation of interval halving. So I'd say "binary search" is fine here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'd use "binary search" to mean "progressively discarding half of the search space", whether or not that space happens to be an interval. Others may insist that it should only be applied to an interval search, but I've no idea what the general term should be in that case.